# Adding watermark process is way too slow using C# Microsoft.Word.Interop. Can I make it faster?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

my app first opens the word document as follows:

```
Application wordApp = new Application();
                wordApp.Visible = false;
                wordApp.ScreenUpdating = false;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = null;
                wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Open(datei.pfad, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o);
                wordDoc.Activate();
```

And then it adds watermark to all the selected documents:

```
                foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in wordDoc.Sections)
                {

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape wordShapeFirstPage = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Shapes.AddTextEffect
                     (Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, "© aQua-Institut GmbH", "Calibri", (float)30, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                     Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 150, 350, o);

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape wordShapePrimary = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary].Shapes.AddTextEffect
                    (Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, "© aQua-Institut GmbH", "Calibri", (float)30, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                    Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 150, 350, o);

                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape wordShapeEvenPages = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages].Shapes.AddTextEffect
                   (Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, "© aQua-Institut GmbH", "Calibri", (float)30, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
                   Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 150, 350, o);

                    List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape> wordShapeList = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape>();

                    wordShapeList.Add(wordShapePrimary);
                    wordShapeList.Add(wordShapeFirstPage);
                    wordShapeList.Add(wordShapeEvenPages);

                    foreach (Shape wordShape in wordShapeList)
                    {
                        wordShape.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                        wordShape.Fill.Solid();
                        wordShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (Int32)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorGray15;
                        wordShape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                        wordShape.WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = -1;
                        wordShape.WrapFormat.Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapBehind;
                        wordShape.Rotation = -45;
                        wordShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin;
                        wordShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin;
                       
                    }
                }
```

Finally, all the documents are saved:

```
wordDoc.SaveAs2(datei.neuesDateiverzeichnis + "\\" + datei.neuerDateiname + ".docx", ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
            wordDoc.Close();
            wordApp.Quit();
```

It does work, but it takes way too much time if size of documents is big or formats of documents are a complicated like images on header section. I'd like to make it faster. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forgot to mention how long it takes. For a document that contains images and tables whose size is roughly 1.5 MB, it takes about 4-5 minutes to add watermark.

Comment: I don't know, but does it make any difference if you process the document in the other direction (i.e. add watermarks at the end of the document first). Also, for substantial updates to Word documents it can help to use UndoClear from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that my app added watermark to all the sections, not pages was the problem since some documents have more than 2 section on one page, so it looped the code for all the sections. Here is the new code:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Section section in wordDoc.Sections)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter firstPageHeader = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage];

            List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape> wordShapeList = new List<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape>();

            if (firstPageHeader.LinkToPrevious == false)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape wordShapeFirstPage = firstPageHeader.Shapes.AddTextEffect
             (Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, "WATERMARK", "Calibri", (float)30, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
             Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0, o);
                wordShapeList.Add(wordShapeFirstPage); 

            }

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter primaryHeader = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary];

            if (primaryHeader.LinkToPrevious == false)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape wordShapePrimary = primaryHeader.Shapes.AddTextEffect
          (Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, "WATERMARK", "Calibri", (float)30, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
          Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0, o);
                wordShapeList.Add(wordShapePrimary); 
            }

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.HeaderFooter evenHeader = section.Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterEvenPages];

            if (evenHeader.LinkToPrevious == false)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Shape wordShapeEvenPages = evenHeader.Shapes.AddTextEffect
           (Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoPresetTextEffect.msoTextEffect1, "WATERMARK", "Calibri", (float)30, Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue,
           Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse, 0, 0, o);
                wordShapeList.Add(wordShapeEvenPages);
            }

            foreach (Shape wordShape in wordShapeList)

            {
                wordShape.Fill.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
                wordShape.Fill.Solid();
                wordShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = (Int32)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdColor.wdColorGray15;
                wordShape.Line.Visible = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoFalse;
                wordShape.WrapFormat.AllowOverlap = -1;
                wordShape.WrapFormat.Type = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdWrapType.wdWrapBehind;
                wordShape.Rotation = -45;
                wordShape.RelativeHorizontalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeHorizontalPosition.wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin;
                wordShape.RelativeVerticalPosition = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdRelativeVerticalPosition.wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin;
                wordShape.Left = (float)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
                wordShape.Top = (float)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdShapePosition.wdShapeCenter;
            }
        }
```